# Kentico OnlineMarketingContext.CurrentContact in send email process step

Tags: kentico

Using a process in Online marketing I want to use a custom macro in the "send email" email step and was expecting to be able to get a reference to the current contact in the macro using **OnlineMarketingContext.CurrentContact**. However this returns a reference to the global Adminstrator contact instead of the contact currently being processed. How can I get a reference to the contact for which the process was initiated in my custom macro ?

Answer (score 0):

In marketing automation you are not in the context of that contact so you can't use `OnlineMarketingContext.CurrentContact`.

Use just `Contact`, e.g. .`Contact.ContactEmail` or `Contact.ContactFirstName`.